# Spring Security Authoriaztion

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

There is one web application created using Spring 3.2 + Hibernate 4 + maven.

Now I want to do authenticate and authorization based on user role. As of now I am not concentrating on authentication. Lets say user is valid and I have a roles somewhere in the object.

Now I want to get started with the authorization part. I am new and not sure how to proceed. I did some R & D on net but it seems quite tough.

I have one document in which how I need to do is written.There are some question I would like to ask :

- A Role Based Access Control framework is adopted to control permission : Please explain little bit. I think it is talking about authorization based on role.
- UI Level Permissions, Method Level Permissions, Object Level Permissions : I search on net and found Object level permission is something like create ACL( access control list ) and it seems very complex. why it s required to have object level permission.
- Dynamic permission evaluation on object : Why it is required.
- I search on net found @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize is there on method level permission. Is Spring AOP is required to do this. As of now we are now using Spring AOP in application.
  Please help me how to start.

Answer (score 0):

for authorization you need to configure few things in security.xml file

first you  need to load the roles on which you want to authorize

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
            <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
                <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

You need create a bean name userDetailsService to fetch all the roles from DB or any other source.

Now you need to configure a decision manager by configuring a role voter saying that on which type of roles you want to authorize

```
 <bean id="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false"/>
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="roleVoter"/>
```

after that you need to configure a filter security interceptor where you need to define a intercept url where you need to define a protected resource uri and access with the roles you want to protect

```
 <bean id="fsi" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"/>
        <property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <sec:filter-security-metadata-source lowercase-comparisons="true">
                 <sec:intercept-url pattern='/test**' access='testRole'/>
```

Comment: thanks. Can you please give me step by step guide. I am new in this.